# Unable to scroll web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Unable to scroll my web page while using below code.

here is live demo of the issue [EXAMPLE](http://stefanvblog.com/category/top5/)

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#navmenu').addClass("menugore");
        $('#navmenu').removeClass("menudole"); 
    } else {
        $('#navmenu').removeClass("menugore");
        $('#navmenu').addClass("menudole"); 
    }
});   
</script>
```

Comment: I don't anu bug. can you explain what it is?

Comment: *"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself**. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."*

Comment: Try to scroll up... screen will blink..

Comment: The problem, from what i can see, is that the Top 5 section just isn't 'long' enough. If/when you add more content the bug will correct itself. That said it's still not good design. I would suggest to decrease the `scrollTop`.

Comment: What's more, in Firefox the scrollback happens on the news page too... except for when the console is opened though...

Comment: I hope now is all ok.. i decrease the scrollTop ... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this 'bug' lies within the HTML design.

By changing the `css` properties of your `#navmenu`, you're removing all of the `height` from the body which was applied by `#navmenu` - meaning that once this happens, you may no longer be `> 100` from the top of the document.

A good solution would be to keep your `#navmenu` unchanged, and instead hide/show a new element which has the properties of `.menugore`.